# Does workshop provide any unique bonuses?

Tags: xcom-2

Workshop provides engineer replacements for nearby rooms, allowing you to staff them with less engineers total, I got that. But do workshop provide any unique bonuses? I.e. do GREMLINs give better rate increases or do they count as additional slot?

What if I have big enough supply of engineers to staff on all position - will I get anything extra from workshop or will it be useless waste of space better replaced by another room?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Gremlins do exactly the same thing that engineers do, nothing more, nothing less. Staffing a Gremlin in a slot has the exact same effect as staffing it with a regular human engineer, and vice versa.

Comment: So, workshop is useless if I have large enough engineering staff after all?

Comment: @OlegV.Volkov I suppose so, yes.

Answer (score -3):

A higher engineer level will actually provide more staffing gremlins than a low level engineer.  My low level engineer granted +2 Staffing Gremlins for 1 slot, but a level 10 engineer granted +7 Staffing Gremlins (almost overkill lol).

And those Staffing Gremlins all received the same level, so the affect they had on other facilities were just as if I had placed a level 10 engineer in each one.

Comment: "level 10 engineer" - unless you install mods or mess with ini settings, I don't think engineers actually level.

Comment: Well, I don't have mods and haven't installed any ini settings, but if you go into your console and add an engineer/scientist you can assign a level to that engineer and scientist

Comment: Well, that is interesting (seriously, very cool - might have to mod that in myself) - but does absolutely only apply to non-vanilla staff in the game. Saying "yes, if you edit the stats of stuff" is equally relevant to "GREMLINs are better than engineers, if you edit the inis / console values to make it so".

Comment: It's not a mod, and you're not editing the stats of stuff. It's a default console command, no different than adding resources to your inventory.  Meaning, in vanilla XCOM, that's the way it is designed